# Is there a similar function in complex number system corresponding to logarithim in real number system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

i notice that there are $e^{i\theta}$ in math,so is there a similar function in complex number system corresponding to logarithim in real number system?

Comment: Yes there is, but it is multivalued. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  See the Wikipedia page on the [complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem because $(z\mapsto e^z) : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is not an injection, e.g. $e^0 = 1 = e^{2\pi i}$. You can define a relation $R$ such that $z_1 R z_2 \iff z_2 = e^{z_1}$, but this relation would not be a function. Using the axiom of choice you could make it a function, i.e. for pick one element from each inverse image set and in fact mathematicians already did such thing: there is something known as principal value or principal branch. As others pointed out, there is nice [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), but you could also try [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) and of course [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=complex+logarithm).

Best luck!